# Remove the extension of filename and convert camelCase to snake case using regex vscode snippets?

Tags: javascript, regex, vscode-snippets

I need to create many files on same structure. The modules exported and filename have some relation. I have to convert. Example input and outputs.

```
startNewGame.ts => start-new-game
gameOver.ts => game-over
ALongNameForAFile.ts=> a-long-name-for-file
short.ts => short
```

My current regex is

```
${TM_FILENAME/([A-Z])/-${1:/downcase}/g}
```

For now I am only able to remove change capital letter so small and add `-`. There are two problems

- I am unable to remove `.ts`
- There is extra `-` in the start.

**Note:** I am using this in vscode snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close on removing the file name extension: use `TM_FILENAME_BASE` instead.  See [vscode snippet variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables).

```
"filename change": {
  "prefix": "_co",
  "body": [
    "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(^[A-Z])|([A-Z])/${2:+-}${2:/downcase}${1:/downcase}/g}",
  ],
  "description": ""
},
```

Since the leading `-` only happens when there is a capital letter at the start, I found it easiest to handle that case separately.  So the regex is now:

`(^[A-Z])|([A-Z])`  // the order is important.

`${2:+-}` is a conditional, add the `-` only if there is a capture group 2.

Comment: Working on the extra `-` at the start which I see only with this filename:  `ALongNameForAFile.ts`

Comment: I edited th4e answer.  Let me know if that works.